# Table and Tikz figure not displaying using this article template

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Journal Article
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (9/9/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Frits Wenneker (http://www.howtotex.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float} % Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text
\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\algsetup{linenosize=\small}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
%\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}} % Roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Improved Cuckoo Search for TTP} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{17pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{An Improved Cuckoo Search algorithm for the Traveling Tournament Problem}} % Article title


\author{
\large
\textsc{Sandile Saul, Adewumi Aderemi Oluyinka}\thanks{The financial assistance of the National Research Foundation (NRF) towards this research is hereby acknowledged. Opinions expressed and conclusions arrived at, are those of the author and are not necessarily to be attributed to the NRF.}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize School of Mathematics, Statistics and Computer Science\\ \normalsize University of Kwazulu-Natal,
Westville Campus,\\ \normalsize Durban, 4000,
South Africa\\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:adewumia@ukzn.ac.za}{adewumia@ukzn.ac.za} % Your email address
\vspace{-5mm}
}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}

\noindent Scheduling of professional sports is one of many researched practical problems in combinatorial optimization. 
\textbf{Keywords:} Sport Scheduling, Traveling Tournament Problem, Double Round-Robin Tournament, Improved Cuckoo Search.
\end{abstract}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}


\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{S}cheduling is one of many researched practical problems in combinatorial optimization. It involves developing a timetable of events within a specified time frame and giv

\begin{equation}
\textit{Minimize} \ \sum _{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2(n-1)} d_{ij}x_{ijk}
\end{equation}
Subject to the following constraints:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n} (x_{i,j,k} + x_{j,i,k})= 1\:\:\:\: 
\end{equation}
\mbox{ $\forall{1\leq{i} \leq{n}}$} \ \ \mbox{$ \forall{1\leq{k}\leq{2(n-1)}}$}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{2(n-1)} x_{i,j,k} = 1\:\:\:\: \forall{{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}}, \:\:\forall{{1\leq{j}\leq{n}}}, \:\:i\neq{j}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_{i,j,k} + x_{j,i,k+1} \leq{1}\:\:\:\: \forall{{1\leq{i\neq{j}}\leq{n}}}, 
\end{equation}
 \mbox{$\forall{{1\leq{k}\leq{2n-3}}}$}
 \begin{equation}
x_{j,i,k} + x_{i,j,k+1} \leq{1}\:\:\:\: \forall{{1\leq{i\neq{j}}\leq{n}}},
\end{equation}
 \mbox{$\forall{{1\leq{k}\leq{2n-3}}}$}
 \begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{s=k}^{k+3} x_{i,j,s} \leq{3}\:\:\:\: \forall{{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}},  \:\:\forall{{1\leq{k}\leq{2n-5}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{s=k}^{k+3} x_{j,i,s} \leq{3}\:\:\:\: \forall{{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}},  \:\:\forall{{1\leq{k}\leq{2n-5}}}
\end{equation}
Where:\\
$n$ : represents the number of teams\\
$i$ : a team index\\
$j$ : a team index\\
$k$ : represents a time slot or a round\\
$d_{ij}$ : is the distance between team \textit{i's} home venue and team \textit{j's} home.\\
\begin{equation*}
 x_{ijk} = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    0, & \text{if team $i$ is playing at home }\\
    & \text{ in slot or round $k$,}\\
    1, &  \text{Otherwise.}\\
  \end{array} \right\}
\end{equation*}
\section{Methods 1} 
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  back line/.style={densely dotted},
  cross line/.style={preaction={draw=white, -,line width=8pt}}]
\node (A) {$8$};
\node (B)[below of=A] {$1$};
\node (C) [node distance=1.5cm, right of=B, below of=B]{$2$};
\node (D) [node distance=1.5cm, left of=C, below of=B]{$7$};
\node (E) [node distance=1.5cm, below of=C]{$3$};
\node (F) [node distance=3.0cm, left of=E]{$6$};
\node (G) [node distance=0.8cm, left of=E, below of=E]{$4$};
\node (H) [node distance=0.8cm, right of=G, below of=F]{$5$};
\draw[cross line] (B) -- (C);
\draw[cross line] (C) -- (E);
\draw[cross line] (E) -- (G);
%\draw[cross line] (G) -- (H);
\draw[cross line] (H) -- (F);
\draw[cross line] (F) -- (D);
\draw[cross line] (D) -- (B);
\draw[<->, dashed] (C) to node {} (D);
\draw[<->, dashed] (F) to node {} (E);
\draw[<->, dashed] (G) to node {} (H);
\draw[<->, dashed] (A) to node {} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Polygon method for $n$ = 8.}
%Figure 1: Polygon method for $n$ = 8.
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\section{Methods 2}
\begin{table}{H}
\caption{Results produced by the execution of the polygon method.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
\toprule(r){1-8}
$T_i \textbackslash k$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
 \midrule
1 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5 & 3\\ 
2 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 8\\
3 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 1\\
4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 8 & 2 & 7\\
5 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 1 & 6\\
6 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 5\\
7 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4\\
8 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Example table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Name} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
First name & Last Name & Grade \\
\midrule
John & Doe & $7.5$ \\
Richard & Miles & $2$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{thebibliography}{99} % Bibliography - this is intentionally simple in this template

\bibitem[Figueredo and Wolf, 2009]{Figueredo:2009dg}
Figueredo, A.~J. and Wolf, P. S.~A. (2009).
\newblock Assortative pairing and life history strategy - a cross-cultural
  study.
\newblock {\em Human Nature}, 20:317--330.

\end{thebibliography}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr Here is the codes of a minimal document for u to run by urself. The figure and table that is not displaying is under method 1 and 2. Also I want to know how to add extra author seperately using that template too.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. Instead, edit your original question to include the additional information.

Comment: @Alex replace `[h!]` by `[H]` (after `\begin{figure}`) and replace `{H}` by `[H]` (after `\begin{table}`) and try again.

Comment: @cfr I have noted your point,it wont happen again.

Comment: @Ignasi.. Your careful observation and suggestion worked out well. The tables and the pictures are now displaying. I also need a clue on how to include second author and address seperately instead of merging them together.

Comment: @Alex Do you know that `\author` allows more than one author inside? `\author{First author\\first affiliation.... \and Second author\\Second affiliation \and Third author ... \and ...}`

Comment: @Ignasi it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ignasi An answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved after correcting two typing errors.

Instead of `\begin{figure}[h!]` type `\begin{figure}[H]` and replace `\begin{table}{H}` by `\begin{table}[H]`.

If you want to introduce different authors with different affiliations, use `\and` inside `\author` command:

```
\author{
\large
\textsc{Sandile Saul}\thanks{The financial assistance of the National Research Foundation (NRF) towards this research is hereby acknowledged. Opinions expressed and conclusions arrived at, are those of the author and are not necessarily to be attributed to the NRF.}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize School of Mathematics, Statistics and Computer Science\\ \normalsize University of Kwazulu-Natal,
Westville Campus,\\ \normalsize Durban, 4000,
South Africa\\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:adewumia@ukzn.ac.za}{adewumia@ukzn.ac.za} % Your email address
\and %<------------------------------- 
\large
\textsc{Adewumi Aderemi Oluyinka}\\[2mm] % Your name
\normalsize School of Mathematics, Statistics and Computer Science\\ \normalsize University of Kwazulu-Natal,
Westville Campus,\\ \normalsize Durban, 4000,
South Africa\\ % Your institution
\normalsize \href{mailto:adewumia@ukzn.ac.za}{adewumia@ukzn.ac.za} % Your email address
}
```

[image]